# What is the best way to structure relationships stored across classes?

Tags: python, oop

I am attempting to build a game environment in python that I can then utilize for a reinforcement learning application.  To accomplish this, I see that applying an OOP approach will integrate best with common Reinforcement Learning methodologies.  I am new to OOP, however, and have some questions regarding the class relationships.  Here are my class definitions:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, n_players, avg_hands_blinds, starting_chips, table_cnt, verbose):
        self.n_players = n_players * table_cnt
        self.starting_chips = starting_chips
        self.table_cnt = table_cnt
        self.tables = []
        for table in range(self.table_cnt):
            self.tables.append(Table(int(n_players/table_cnt)))
        self.players = []
        for i, player in enumerate(range(self.n_players)):
            table_no = int(i/table_cnt)
            self.players.append(Player(i, starting_chips, table_no))

    def __repr__(self):
        self.out_list = []
        self.out_list.append(f'Number of players: {self.n_players}')
        return self.out_list


class Tables:
    def __init__(self, n_players):
        self.n_players = n_players
        self.table_hands = []


class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_no, starting_chips, table_no):
        self.player_no = player_no
        self.table_no = table_no
        self.chips = Chips(starting_chips)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'player_no: {self.player_no} table_no: {self.table_no} chips: {self.chips}'
```

My question relates to how I should store information about the table assignments.  For example, I have defined Player instances at the game level to facilitate awareness of their overall status in a game.  During the game, players will need to be reassigned to different tables to re-balance tables as players are knocked out.

At the same time, each Table instance will need to have an "awareness" of which players are sitting at the table (to execute Hand instances, for example).

My question is this:  how do I enable both transfer of players between tables and enable my Table instances to conduct operations on the relevant players?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea for `Table` to have logic pertaining to moving players around. It should have public methods defined allowing players to be removed or moved to other instance but the logic should be controlled by `Game` class. `Table` should also take instances of players as a property instead of `Game`

Comment: `__repr__` is supposed to return a `str` value, not a `list` value.

Comment: Whenever you want to know the "best" way to do something, you need to define what criteria should be used to make the determination. i.e. What are you hoping to minimize, maximize, or otherwise optimize?